# Who swears in the president if all of the sitting members of the Supreme Court are dead?

Tags: united-states, president, senate, supreme-court, inauguration

The Chief Justice of the Supreme Court is supposed to swear in president-elect of the United States. If there is no sitting Chief Justice, another member of the court would swear the president and vice-president in.

However, what if the entire court does not have any sitting members. Who swears in the president then? Ideally, the Senate would have to approve a new presidential nominee. But what if the entire court is killed in a tragic accident on their way to the new president's inauguration on the 20th of January?

Comment: Downvoted because the question is based on a misconception,  Anyone legally authorized to take oaths can swear in the President.  For instance, Lyndon Johnson was sworn in by a Texas judge after Kennedy was killed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anyone who is empowered to administer federal oaths.  There's no requirement that it be a member of the supreme court; that is only a tradition. In fact, after Kennedy's assassination, Johnson was sworn in by a district court judge.

Comment: The Constitution just says the president will take the oath. It doesn't say anything about anyone administering it.

Comment: However oaths do need to be administered by a notary to be legal, that's not a Constitutional requirement, but a common law requirement